# Prove $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=0$ iff $\lim_{x\to p}|f(x)|=0$.

Tags: limits, functions, multivariable-calculus

The hint I was given was to use both the /epsilon - /delta definition and the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? In particular, which direction do you have trouble with?

Comment: $|f(x) - 0| = ||f(x)|-0|.$

Comment: here is what i have so far.. i'm just not sure if it's correct. also I didn't use Cauchy Schwarz.
(sorry im new to here and i'm not familiar with mathjax)
let lim f(x) = 0  (f is a function from set A in the Reals to the Reals)
then there exist a delta such that if x is in A and 0 < |x-p| <delta then |f(x)-0| < epsilon.
By the (full/generalized) Triangle Inequality, 
| |f(x)| - |0| | <= | f(x) - 0 |
So | |f(x)| - |0| | < epsilon
Thus lim |f(x)| = 0.

Comment: @eunhye I really can't imagine a good use for Cauchy-Schwarz here, so don't worry that you haven't used it.

Comment: HINT:  $$|f(x)|^2=\sum_{n=1}^N f_n^2(x)\,\ge \,\frac1N \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |f_n(x)|\right)^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) \to 0$, then clearly $|f(x)| \to |0| = 0$.

For the other direction, remember the *squeeze theorem* and note that:
$$-|f(x)| \le f(x) \le |f(x)|$$

Comment: I can only guess, but guessing by the multivariable-calculus tag, OP has a vector valued function, so $|\cdot| : \mathbb {R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I must admit I didn't check the tag and that wasn't clear from the notation of the limits. Perhaps OP can confirm / clarify?

Comment: Honestly, OP was so vague and showed so little effort, that both interpretations could be correct...

Comment: sorry i definitely was vague. f is a vector valued function.

Comment: @eunhye But in your comment above, you say that $f$ is a function from $A \to \mathbb R$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb R$.  How can it also be vector-valued?

Comment: sorry i meant R^n to R^m.......